# Converting mxd to earlier version using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, mxd

I am running arcmap 10.2.2 but need to open an mxd saved using 10.3. I do not have access to 10.3. I have an arcpy tool which will do the conversion but it is not working from within 10.2.2.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this from within 10.2.2. I get an error message saying I do not have write access to the file.

The script is as follows:

```
import arcpy, sys, os, string 

mxdList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";") 
outloc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
version = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

suffix = "_"+ version.replace(".", "")

for item in mxdList: 
    item = item.strip('\'') 
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(item) 
    base = os.path.basename(item) 
    base = os.path.splitext(base)[0] + suffix + os.path.splitext(base)[1] 
    mxd.saveACopy(outloc + os.sep + base, version)
    arcpy.AddMessage(os.path.basename(item) + " has been converted")
```

Comment: No, you will not be able to open the MXD in 10.2, you need to 'save as' from 10.3. I think it's time to 'phone a friend' with access to 10.3 and get them to do it for you (or upgrade at least one workstation).

Comment: I agree with Michael Miles-Stimeson.

Comment: Vote for these 3 Ideas on mxd forward and backwards compatibility: https://community.esri.com/ideas/11608-backwardforward-compatibility, https://community.esri.com/ideas/5662, https://community.esri.com/ideas/3400

Answer (score 2):

From reading the [10.3.1 Help on Saving to previous versions of ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/saving-a-map.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_47EBF84D55D545B68A33CB778A653481):

> Note that documents from ArcGIS 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 and related releases,
>   such as 10.3.1, are directly compatible with each other

Consequently, I think you should use 10.2 to try and open the MXD saved at 10.3.

If it will not open, and the cause is not obvious from any error message returned then that would seem to be worth asking as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I was using 10.2.2 but getting a message saying that the mxd had been saved with a later version so it seems as if they are not compatible. I had to use 10.3 and then save the mxd as 10.1 - 10.2. That worked. I am surprised though that 10.2.2 would not be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This comment indicates **MXD Doctor** can open (at least some) future versions of map compositions and save as current version: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281789/108