# Opening MXD saved in one version using earlier version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, mxd, arcgis-10.6

Working in an enterprise system. We need to determine if everyone needs to update to 10.6 at the same time for mxd cross-compatibility or can we update from 10.5 as needed.

Answer (score 10):

You need to save a copy of the mxd to an earlier version if you have saved the mxd in ArcGIS latest version 10.6.

Based on ArcGIS help: [Saving a map](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/saving-a-map.htm):

> New documents cannot be opened in earlier versions of the software;
>   however, you can use the **Save A Copy** command to make a copy of a map
>   document so you can open and work with it in previous versions of
>   ArcGIS.

Comment: Just tested 10.6 vs 10.5, can confirm must use Save A Copy in order for it to work

Answer (score 4):

The MXD Doctor will also work. The tool can be found here..

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\Tools
```

Answer (score 4):

As [@JordanMiller mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269651/115), the MXD Doctor can fix the mxds, but not just looking backwards, but from future releases.  I just used the 10.5 MXD Doctor to backward save some 10.6 mxds for use in 10.5 (I had to downgrade for HEC-GeoHMS and HEC-GeoRAS, and didn't think to save as before uninstalling 10.6).

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue and I used Python script to fix it... You need to open a blank document in ArcMap, then open the Python window. Then copy/paste the following code, just repoint the path to the proper mxds...

```
mxd_path=r"path/to/the/10_5_mxd.mxd"
mxd= arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
mxd.saveACopy(r"path/to/the/new/10_4_mxd.mxd","10.1")
```

In ArcMap 10.6 the list of options for the version parameter are: ['10.1', '10.0', '8.3', '10.3', '9.0', '9.2', '9.3']

Answer (score 0):

To convert 10.8 in 10.7 i had to use 10.6 as temporary step, direkt use of saveACopy lead to Error.

```
import arcpy #  10.7

mxdFile = r"D:\Dir\Chart.mxd" #  10.8
mxdArc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdFile)
mxdArc.saveACopy(mxdFile.replace(".mxd", "_10.6.mxd"), "10.6")
del mxdArc
mxdArc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdFile.replace(".mxd", "_10.6.mxd"))
mxdArc.saveACopy(mxdFile.replace(".mxd", "_10.7.mxd"))
```